# C# WPF Combobox dropdown list to multiple columns

Tags: c#, wpf, list, combobox, multiple-columns

Is it possible to "force" the combobox items in list to appear in say two columns?

For example like this:

### CB Selected Item

### CB Item 1 | CB Item 4

### CB Item 2 | CB Item 5

### CB Item 3 |

Comment: Any particular reason why you want it to go vertical then horizontal?

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan We know nothing about what matters *more* to Kristo, and if you’re going to blame someone for caring about UI (or for being curious), then I’m not with you.

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan I was thinking functionality wise, if he had 100 entries, to get to the 50th the client would have to scroll to the bottom of the `ComboBox` list (since they'd be ordered in half (vertically) instead of two-by-two), instead of halfway. What happens when he has thousands?

Comment: If he had 100 or 1000 entries, he'd better not use a Combo anyway :)

Comment: html doesn't have a multi-column combo box for a reason.

Comment: thanks for all the great feedback guys :) already got something working, but need to develop also some converters to get the height and with according to the amount of content.
my solution has some maximum 30-35 items in the dropdown list, so i will "force" them to maximum 3 columns to have the whole list on the page right away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the ItemsPanel to a WrapPanel, just be careful on the height (you could write a converter to calculate it according to the number of items) :

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Vertical" Width="100" Height="50" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>

    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 2" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 3" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 4" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 5" />
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Would this also work if you use an `ItemTemplate` for the `ComboBox` and using an `ItemsSource` instead of putting in the `ComboBoxItem` individually?

Comment: yes it does work well with `DataTemplate` and `ItemsSource` ... thanks a lot @mathieu :)

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can, here's the XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBox">
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="2"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

Now a simple test, adding numbers from 0 to 8 gives:

[image: uniform grid in combo box]

Now you can style it all you want... :)

Of course every item (every number, in this particular case) is separate, clickable item, just so there are no misunderstandings.

[EDIT] I have just noticed you want to do it 'the opposite way', that is in 'rows' direction, if so, then maybe it's better to use the `WrapPanel` instead, as someone suggested in the other answer. The `UniformGrid` fills the grid in the column-wise direction first.

Maybe there's a way to do it with `UniformGrid`, but there's no apparent and easy one-click change (I was wrong here before :) )

Comment: you represent it as a transpose matrix compared to the original, which doesn't give what the op wants

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan Yeah, I have noticed that, hence the EDIT section. :)

Comment: thanks anyways for the input, i might use UniformGrid later on ;)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to put a `WrapPanel` into the `ItemsPanel` of the combobox.

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="100" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 2" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 3" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 4" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 5" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 6" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 7" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 8" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 9" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 10" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 11" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 12" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 13" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 14" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 15" />
</ComboBox>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could try changing the control template to use Grid and use converters to decide what column and row the cbitems are. I am not sure how you'd handle the selected item though.

Comment: it's about flow layout. not columns.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean. Looking at the example that people provided, I realize what he/she was asking for.